# Cannot edit values in dynamically created form

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to:

- Dynamically create an input form based on a schema.
- Prefill the form.
- Allow edits.
- Get final data on submit.

What I have created is a small component (available in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-shape-c06yg?file=/src/AutoForm.tsx)) to do this:

```
import { Stack, TextField } from "@fluentui/react";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export interface FieldsDescriptor<T> {
  labels: Record<keyof T, string>;
}

export interface AutoFormProps<T> {
  metadata: FieldsDescriptor<T>;
  data: T;
}

function createInputField(
  label: string,
  value: string,
  onChange: (newValue?: string) => void
): React.ReactNode {
  return (
    <TextField label={label} value={value} onChange={(e, v) => onChange(v)} />
  );
}

function t2strrec<T>(input: T): Record<keyof T, string> {
  const res: any = {};
  for (const field in input) {
    res[field] = String(input[field]);
  }
  return res;
}

export function withAutoForm<T>() {
  return (props: AutoFormProps<T>) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState<Record<keyof T, string>>(
      t2strrec(props.data)
    );

    const generateFields = (): Array<React.ReactNode> => {
      const result: Array<React.ReactNode> = [];
      for (const k in data) {
        const el = (
          <Stack.Item key={k}>
            {createInputField(
              props.metadata.labels[k],
              String(props.data[k]),
              (v) => {
                setData({ ...data, [k]: v });
              }
            )}
          </Stack.Item>
        );
        result.push(el);
      }
      return result;
    };

    return <Stack>{generateFields()}</Stack>;
  };
}
```

Which I use like this:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { withAutoForm } from "./AutoForm";

interface MyForm {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
}

export default function App() {
  const Form = withAutoForm<MyForm>();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>My form</h1>
      <div>
        <Form
          metadata={{
            labels: {
              name: "Name",
              surname: "Surname"
            }
          }}
          data={{ name: "Shinji", surname: "Ikari" }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I can get the form to correctly show, but I cannot modify the field values. I know I am doing something stupid with the state management, can you help me figure out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing props.data to createInputField, you need to pass it from State

```
const generateFields = (): Array<React.ReactNode> => {
      const result: Array<React.ReactNode> = [];
      for (const k in data) {
        const el = (
          <Stack.Item key={k}>
            {createInputField(
              props.metadata.labels[k],
              String(data[k]/*<---change to state*/),
              (v) => {
                console.log(data);
                
                setData({ ...data, [k]: v });
              }
            )}
          </Stack.Item>
        );
        result.push(el);
      }
      return result;
    };
```

Comment: My god what a stupid mistake!!! I thought I was actually using the data from the state... So embarrassed. Good catch man!